# Want to write nested dictionaries into SQL table as a single record ( Error : Not enough parameters for the SQL statement )

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write the nested dictionaries into SQL Table in a single row.

I want to join the (User_ID ) Dictionary values and (V.Values()) into single row.

If I try to combine into single row, I'm getting error message like

**" IndexError: tuple index out of range "**

**" ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement "**

Since it is a nested dictionary, I don't know how to combine. I tried some methods with the help of internet but it is no use.

Does anyone can solve this issue, It would be really helpful for me.

I think the problem is in the for loop, sql query execution. Let me know any ideas to solve the problem.

Working Code :

```
import mysql.connector as conn

db = conn.connect(
    host ="Localhost",
    user ="root",
    passwd ="admin",
    )

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_00")

db = conn.connect(
    host ="Localhost",
    user ="root",
    passwd ="admin",
    database = "EMPLOYEE_DETAILS_00"
    )

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Details_Nested ( User_ID int(10), Name VARCHAR(255), Age int(3), Occupation VARCHAR(255), Department VARCHAR(255), Salary int(10), Address VARCHAR(255) ) ")

user_details = {}

while True:
    user_input = input(" You're Operation Please ( New / View ) Details : ").lower()

    if user_input == 'new':
        create_user_ID = input(" Enter the user ID :  ")
        user_details[create_user_ID] = {}
        user_name = input(" Enter the user name : ")
        user_details[create_user_ID]['Name'] = user_name
        user_age = int(input(" Enter the Age : "))
        user_details[create_user_ID]['Age'] = user_age
        user_occupation = input(" Enter the users occupation : ")
        user_details[create_user_ID]['Occupation'] = user_occupation
        user_department = input(" user department : ")
        user_details[create_user_ID]['Department'] = user_department
        user_income = int(input(" Enter the salary details : "))
        user_details[create_user_ID]['Salary'] = user_income
        user_address = input(" Enter the Address details ")
        user_details[create_user_ID]['Address'] = user_address

        print(f" New User account {create_user_ID} has been successfully created")
        for detail in user_details.items():
            print(detail)

        for k,v in user_details.items():
            columns = ", ".join(["User_ID"] + list(v.keys()))
            values = ", ".join([k] + [str(v) for v in v.values()])

            sql = 'INSERT INTO Details (User_ID, Name, Age, Occupation, Department, Salary, Address) VALUES ("%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s")'
            cursor.execute(sql, (values,))
            db.commit()

        process = input(" Do you want to continue the Account creation process (YES / NO ) : ").lower()
        if process == 'no':
            break

    elif user_input == 'view':
        user_input = input("Enter the User_ID :")
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Details WHERE USER_ID = '%s'" % (user_input))
        record = cursor.fetchall()
        print(record)
        break

    else:
        print(" Please enter the proper command to execute (new / view)")
```

Code - Output( User-defined Values)

```
{'1101': {'Name': 'Test_User', 'Age': Test_Age, 'Occupation': 'Test_Occupation'}}
```

SQL Output (For Example)

```
User_ID  User_name    User_Age    User_Occupation

1101     Test_User    Test_Age    Test_Occupation
```

Let me know any solution for this problem.

Thanks for your time in Advance !!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an issue with:

`sql = 'INSERT INTO Details (User_ID, Name, Age, Occupation, Department, Salary, Address) VALUES ("%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s")'`

some of your values are `int` not `string` type such as:

> `User_ID`
>
> `Age`
>
> `Salary`

change to

`sql = 'INSERT INTO Details (User_ID, Name, Age, Occupation, Department, Salary, Address) VALUES (%s,"%s",%s,"%s","%s",%s,"%s")'`

[See This for more help](https://pynative.com/python-mysql-select-query-to-fetch-data/)